# Should I create a class just to contain data to be shared by other classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

To be specific let's say I have two classes; **Student** and **Instructor**. Student can register a subject and instructor can be assigned a subject. So will this be a good idea to create a class **Department** that contains list of subjects and both student and instructor can have a subject from that list only. Similarly, some other that meant to be common for both Student and Instructor can be placed in Department class. Class Department may not have any constructor and other methods but just the data.
I am doing this on Python.

Comment: How are subjects represented?

Comment: May be just a List of subject codes to start with.

Comment: If you are just using subject codes, then use a Subject Enum to store them

Comment: And for some other case, should we create a class just as data-container?

Comment: If a subject is a collection of data, rather than a single piece of data (a code, a name, whatever), then a class would be appropriate. However, do keep in mind that you can do both. Enums can hold objects as values as well. Think of an Enum as way to say "I want to create a class, and have these well-defined objects instantiated immediately"

Comment: This sounds like a use-case for an `enum` class